# Need a circle with texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

i'd like to have a circle with a texture on one side in three.js.
I thought about using THREE.CylinderGeometry, but where do I have to add the "materials" in the new THREE.CylinderGeometry(...)-section?

And I don't want to use sprites.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You can now use `THREE.CircleGeometry` to create a textured disk.

Three.js r.75